# Get method by reflection fails

Tags: c#, reflection, overloading

I have the following method delared by *Gl*:

```
public static void Get(int pname, out int @params)
```

I'm trying to get it using reflection in the following way:

```
MethodInfo mGetMethod = typeof(Gl).GetMethod("Get",
                                             BindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Static,
                                             null, 
                                             new Type[] 
                                             { 
                                                 typeof(Int32), 
                                                 typeof(Int32) 
                                             }, 
                                             null);
```

But I have no success. Why?

Is it because the *out* keyword?

Comment: are you using .NET 4?  If so you can use the dynamic keyword to create a reflected object, then call the method directly.  That way you don't need the MethodInfo lookup.  Downside is, if you get it wrong, you get a runtime exception

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `typeof(Int32).MakeByRefType()` for your second parameter.  I.e.:

```
MethodInfo mGetMethod = typeof(Gl).GetMethod("Get", bindingFlags.Public|BindingFlags.Static, null, new Type[] { typeof(Int32), typeof(Int32).MakeByRefType() }, null);
```

Comment: Found it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438065/c-reflection-how-can-i-invoke-a-method-with-an-out-parameter

Answer (score 1):

If you need to specify the specific overload for the method then definitely go with what @Isaac Overacker said. Otherwise just don't specify the parameters:

```
MethodInfo mGetMethod = typeof(Gl).GetMethod("Get", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
```

Answer (score 1):

The out keyword passes the parameter by reference, which is probably your problem.  You will need to flag it as a reference type since C# allows you to overload methods with a byValue and byReference parameter.

Answer (score 0):

How about trying something like this instead:

```
MethodInfo method = this.GetType().GetMethod("Get");
if (method != null)
{
    method.Invoke(this, new object[] { "Arg1", "Arg2", "Arg3" });
}
```