# Callback from dynamically loaded DLL

Tags: c#, dll

I am after ideas on how to call back to a main exe from a dynamically loaded dll ? (NB: this dll will be unloaded at some point after the callback)

Context C#

I am prototyping a service which during development then later on, can update its core. I have a stub main which will do the service calls into the “main dll”. I want to be able to call back into the main exe to tell it to reload the core dll after a fresh copy of the latest dll is done. I have the load – unload working. However I can’t get a callback or update of a passed IntPtr  to work and other similar ideas to work. E.g.

```
    loader.ExecuteStaticMethod(cMain_DLL, "Class1", "My_CallBack", new object[] {out _Count });
```

wont compile

I have used a slightly modified http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/girish.nehte/how-to-unload-an-assembly-loaded-dynamically-using-reflection/ to load and unload the dll, as well as call functions in the dll.

```
        Type[] types = parameters.Select(o=>o.GetType()).ToArray();

        MethodInfo MyMethod = MyType.GetMethod(methodName, types); <= can retun null for some objects
        MyMethod.Invoke(inst, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, parameters, null);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2438065/c-sharp-reflection-how-can-i-invoke-a-method-with-an-out-parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need only reload event, check `EventWaitHandle`. Your stub can `WaitOne()` on that handle and action accordingly once service calls `Set()`.

Comment: Could you please give me a url or example? I am not familiar enough with what you are referring to to know which part is in the main.exe and which is in the loaded dll. Thanks

Comment: Stub part: 
`var reloadEvent = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset, "MyUniqueName');
...
//load your library
...
reloadEvent.WaitOne();
...
//reload here`
Library part:
`var reloadEvent = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset, "MyUniqueName');
// trigger reload
reloadEvent.Set();
`